glue job success as event producer to event bridge and step function as event target
I need to create a eventbridge rule where AWS Glue job success can serve as an event producer for eventbridge and step function as a target to eventbridge ,
the glue job has input arguments and i want to send those input arguments as payload to event target that is step function.
i am trying with input tranformer in event target ,but i am unable to find place holder for accessing glue jobs arguments
event payload of glue job doesnt have arguments details in it
"detail": {
    "jobName": "job name",
    "severity": "INFO",
    "state": "SUCCEEDED",
    "jobRunId": "runid1",
    "message": "Job run succeeded"
  }

